# Simulating Multinomial Logit Data with R

Tags: logistic, simulation

I'm looking to generate fake data to fit a multinomial logit in R? Any code/suggestions on material to look at would be very much appreciated ...

Comment: Can you say a little more? Do you need to control probabilities for each outcome? Do you need to specify particular predictor relationships? Stuff like that may help guide response to your needs.

Comment: Sure. I am looking to generate simulation data that fits a particular relationship with known parameters. That is, I have vector of X's and a set of parameters and want to generate fake data that I can predict from a multinomial logit with the known parameters..hope that makes sense...!

Answer (score 8):

It is really simple to generate multinomial logit regression data. All you need to keep in mind are the normalizing assumptions.

```
# covariate matrix
mX = matrix(rnorm(1000), 200, 5)

# coefficients for each choice
vCoef1 = rep(0, 5)
vCoef2 = rnorm(5)
vCoef3 = rnorm(5)

# vector of probabilities
vProb = cbind(exp(mX%*%vCoef1), exp(mX%*%vCoef2), exp(mX%*%vCoef3))

# multinomial draws
mChoices = t(apply(vProb, 1, rmultinom, n = 1, size = 1))
dfM = cbind.data.frame(y = apply(mChoices, 1, function(x) which(x==1)), mX)
```

Here `mChoices` and `dfM$y` encode the same information differently.

Comment: One thing that threw me off for a second: `vProb` is not a probability, but non-negative number. However, `rmultinom` internally normalizes so they sum to 1.

Comment: @andybega It does indeed -- and that was intended.

Comment: It was just surprising to me. I did something similar but where I manually normalized probabilities to 1 before sampling outcomes without using `rmultinorm`. Makes perfect sense though.

Comment: Thanks for posting this - I've been struggling with randomly generated multinomial logistic regression data for the past few days. Generating binomial logistic regression observations can be done in one line of code: a <- rbinom(n=200, size=1, prob=exp(X%*%Coef)/(1 + exp(X%*%Coef))), but multinomial is a headache.

Comment: And if you want to add a nonzero intercept to the multinomial DGF, modify the above code: `mX = cbind(rep(1, 200), matrix(rnorm(1000), 200, 5)); vCoef1 = rep(0, 6); vCoef2 = rnorm(6); vCoef3 = rnorm(6)` then run the rest of the code as written. For a final check run a multinomial logistic regression on the generated data (remove the intercept coefficient column): `m <- multinom(y ~ ., data = dfM[,-2]); summary(m)`. The values in `vCoef2` and `vCoef3` ought to closely match the coefficients from the regression output.

Comment: @RobertF when I follow your instructions I get estimated coefficients that are quite different from the DGP

Answer (score 4):

In this model with $k$ variables and $d$ categories, let $x = (1,x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_k)$ be one data point including a constant $1$ for the intercept.  There are $d-1$ column vectors $\beta_2, \beta_3, \ldots, \beta_d,$ each of length $k+1,$ that give the relative chances of each category in the ratios

$$p_1:p_2:\cdots:p_d = 1:e^{x\beta_2}:e^{x\beta_3}:\cdots:e^{x\beta_d}.$$

The random response for this data point places a specified number $s$ balls into $d$ bins (one for each category) according to these probabilities.

Thus, to simulate such data you need to

1. Specify the variables--their number $k,$ the number of data points $n,$ and all their values.
2. Specify the number of categories and the $\beta_j$ parameters.
3. Specify the value of $s$ for each data point.
4. Compute the probabilities determined by (1) and (2) according to this model.
5. Use those sizes (3) and probabilities (4) to generate random multinomial outcomes.

This leads to a straightforward `R` implementation.  It randomly generates and stores the variables (1) in an array `X` and, given a randomly-generated array of coefficients (2) and randomly-generated size array (3), computes the probabilities (4) and applies `rmultinom` to each data point (5) to obtain the matrix of responses (one column per category) and store it in the array `y`.

```R
n <- 5e3            # Number of observations
k <- 3              # Number of variables
d <- 4              # Number of categories
size <- 15          # Expected size of each outcome (number of balls selected)

set.seed(17)
xnames <-  paste0("X", seq_len(k))
beta <- matrix(rnorm((k+1) * d), ncol = d, dimnames=list(c("Intercept", xnames), seq_len(d))) 
beta = beta - beta[, 1] # Standardize: category 1 is the reference category
X <- matrix(runif(n * k), n, dimnames = list(NULL, xnames))

p <- (function(h) h / rowSums(h))(exp(cbind(1, X) %*% beta))
s <- 1 + rpois(n, size-1)
y <- t(sapply(seq_len(n), function(i) rmultinom(1, s[i], p[i, ])))
```

With the $n=5000$ observations specified here, the estimates $\hat\beta$ had better be close to the stipulated value of $\beta$!  Using `nnet::multinom` I estimated the coefficients.

```R
library(nnet)
fit <- multinom(y ~ X)
```

Here is a plot comparing all $12$ coefficients to their specified values.  The gray lines are 95% confidence intervals around each estimate.  The agreement is good, indicating this approach agrees with the model assumed by `multinom`.

[image]

The total number of results in each category depend on all the inputs.  The *expected* totals can be computed by multiplying the probabilities $(p_1, \ldots, p_d)$ for each data point times its value of $s$ and adding these up by category:

```R
round(rbind(Expected = s %*% p, Observed = colSums(y)))
```

> ```
>            1     2     3     4
>          880 28799 13837 31623
> Observed 902 28941 13852 31444
> ```

The counts observed in this simulation, by category, are close to the expected counts.

This indicates how you can adjust your simulation to achieve a desired count, set of counts, or (as asked in the question) proportion of counts: you can alter the data points, the coefficients, and the sizes as you will.  How you do this will depend on what aspects of the situation you are willing to vary.  There are so many possibilities that it would take us too far afield to discuss them all here.

Answer (score 2):

```
#Genarating 500 random numbers with zero mean
x = rnorm(500,0)
#Assigning the values of beta1 and beta2
Beta1 = 2
Beta2 = .5
#Calculation of denominator for probability calculation
Denominator= 1+exp(Beta1*x)+exp(Beta2*x)
#Calculating the matrix of probabilities for three choices
vProb = cbind(1/Denominator, exp(x*Beta1)/Denominator, exp(x*Beta2)/Denominator )
# Assigning the value one to maximum probability and zero for rest to get the appropriate choices for value of x
mChoices = t(apply(vProb, 1, rmultinom, n = 1, size = 1))
# Value of Y and X together
dfM = cbind.data.frame(y = apply(mChoices, 1, function(x) which(x==1)), x)
#Adding library for multinomial logit regression
library("nnet")
#We want zero intercept hence x+0 hence the foumula of regression as below
fit<-(multinom(y ~ x + 0, dfM))
#This function uses first y as base class 
#hence upper probability calculation is changed
summary(fit)
#In case we do not keep intercept as zero
fit2<-multinom(y ~ x, dfM)
summary(fit2)
#This also result intercept very close to zero and non significant
#and value of beta as modeled earlier and significant
#running from mlogit package
library(mlogit)
DM<-mlogit.data(dfM, shape="wide",sep="",choice="y",alt.levels=1:3)
#Do not know why -1 is used at two places. I will appreciate if some one can explain
fit3<-mlogit(y~-1|-1+x,data=DM)
summary(fit3)
```

Comment: I think this data generating process is kind more straightforward. Because of the ML estimation of coefficients(Beta1, Beta2) in most of the cases provides the coefficients of alternative levels comparing to the baseline level, these estimators will not be consistent with the true coefficients of DGP(data generating process) in the above answers. However, this DGP generates baseline level (denominator) first so that the estimation of most packages will provide the comparable estimation of the coefficients of alternative levels.